# cross referencing an array of objects with another

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say you have to find out the names of the students that are in both teamBlue & teamRed

Suppose that the arrays are of `unequal length` as shown below, how would you go about approching this.
if someone could just point me in the right direction id really appreciate it

```
teamRed: [
    {
        "id": '1',
        "name": "jenny"
    },
    {
        "id": '2',
        "name": "kenny"
    },
    {
        "id": '3',
        "name": "mike"
    },
     {
        "id": '4',
        "name": "danny"
    }
]


teamBlue: [
    {
        "id": '1',
        "name": "joey"
    },
    {
        "id": '2',
        "name": "kenny"
    },
    {
        "id": '3',
        "name": "mike"
    }
]
```

Comment: build a set for the first array (any of them actually) and cross reference the other array with the set. Reference for Set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that simply using `Array.forEach()` and `Array.find`.

Here is a simple example:

```
const teamRed = [ ... ]
const teamBlue = [ ... ]
const studentsInBothTeams = []

teamRed.forEach(_teamRed => {
  const existsOnTeamBlue = teamBlue.find(
    _teamBlue => _teamBlue.name === _teamRed.name
  )

  if (existsOnTeamBlue) {
    studentsInBothTeams.push(_teamRed)
  }
})

console.log(studentsInBothTeams)
```

The result is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name":"kenny"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "mike"
  }
]
```